# Ranking query from the last x months

Tags: php, mysql, sql, ranking

I want to get all records from the last x months from my MySQL server. Using 2 months for example(Not from last 2 months, like last 60 days, but from the entire past month and so on. If actual month is april, I want all records from february and march).
I've tried some queries and the last one is

```
SELECT id FROM ranking WHERE (end_date BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-01') AND DATE_FORMAT(LAST_DAY(NOW() - INTERVAL 2 MONTH), '%Y-%m-%d'))
```

"end_date" is my date column which is a DATE column "2017-04-07".

That query above just returns nothing and I cant figure out where is the error.

Comment: what data type is end_date?

Comment: Try using this in your query "end_date >= dateadd(month, -2, getdate())". Let me know if it works

Comment: @McNets, It is just an example, haha. The actual query is much bigger and a bit more complex, so I simplified it to cover the "error", and I must admit that I'm terrible at inventing column names :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT id
FROM ranking
WHERE end_date BETWEEN
DATE_ADD(LAST_DAY(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 MONTH)) INTERVAL 1 DAY)
AND LAST_DAY(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH));
```

It calculates dates as like this:

- For start date in range, it subtracts 3 months from current date, gets the last day of that month and adds a day in it to get the first day of next month (1st February in our case)
- For end date, it subtracts one month from current date and gets the last day of that month (31st March in our case)

Comment: Yeah, thats it! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Try without convert it to string, And BETWEEN requires min date first.

```
SELECT id 
FROM ranking 
WHERE end_date BETWEEN LAST_DAY(CAST(NOW() as date) - INTERVAL 2 MONTH 
               AND CAST(NOW() as date)
```

Comment: That will work if I want to get the records from 2 months to now, but as I have said, I want to get just the records from the past months, anyway, thanks for helping